# Use MapReduce on list elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, mapreduce

So I know how to use MapReduce for files where each element is on a line, but I'm trying to use MapReduce on a file with its entries like so:

```
74390,0,6,7,5,2,6,4,10,12,7,6,12,9,4,3,9,1,3,5,9,9,8,5,12,11,4,8,5,9,6,12,12,9,7,9,12,7,8,9,8,8
74391,1,4,2,9,3,5,12,7,6,9,6,8,9,10,12,7,9,9,9,9,5,1,8,4,5,12,6,5,4,3,9,6,8,7,12,11,12,7,8,12,8
74392,0,6,9,3,2,4,9,1,4,7,12,9,12,12,10,6,9,9,5,12,7,12,7,6,8,7,9,5,3,5,9,8,9,12,5,8,4,11,8,6,8
74393,0,8,9,9,7,12,7,12,12,2,9,7,10,7,9,9,9,9,6,4,9,5,6,4,8,8,5,3,5,6,4,1,12,8,12,12,3,8,6,11,5
74394,0,5,9,6,2,4,6,5,6,7,12,8,9,7,9,10,3,9,1,9,8,9,12,7,3,5,12,12,4,12,4,8,9,5,9,12,8,11,6,8,7
74395,1,7,6,7,6,5,2,9,7,1,7,9,12,6,3,9,3,12,10,12,9,9,8,4,12,4,9,6,8,4,9,5,8,12,11,12,8,5,9,8,5
```

The first entry is the index and the second is meaningless for this analysis, and in the following code I remove them. My file has hundreds of thousands of lines like this, and I need to figure out which number appears in each part of the line the most, as these correspond to slots. 
Expected output:

```
0: 1
1: 11
2: 5
...
40: 9
```

What I've got so far:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class topPieceSlot(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        pieces = line.split(',')
        pieces = pieces[2::]
        for item in range(len(pieces)):
            yield str(item)


    def reducer(self, pieces):
        for slot in range(len(pieces)):
            element = str(slot)
            numElements = 0
            for x in pieces:
                total += x
                numElements += 1

        yield element, numElements

if __name__ == '__main__':
    topPieceSlot.run()
```

And it returns nothing. It tells me it needs more than one value to unpack, but I'm not sure why it is only getting one value or if it's even right to begin with. Should I be using 40 variables for it? That seems inefficient and wrong.

Comment: can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: Sample input is there, sample output will add

Comment: @CapnShanty The expected output doesn't look alright to me. Shouldn't slot 0 be equal 6. Slot 1 be equal to 9 ...

Comment: It's not the correct expected output it's just the format :P